# jq filter to transform jsonlines into a single json map

Tags: json, jq, jsonlines, ndjson

Input:

```
{"aa":["a1","a2"]}
{"bb":["a1","b2"]}
```

Wanted output (no worries about potentially duplicate keys):

```
{
  "aa":["a1","a2"],
  "bb":["b1","b2"]
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would undoubtedly be to use the invocation:

```
jq -s add
```

If the input stream is extremely large, it might be better to use reduction, e.g.:

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $i ({}; . + $i)'
```